# Creating a property that LINQ to Entities can translate

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am curious on how to create a property that can be translated by LINQ. Below is a very simple example.

I have a table/class `Category`, that has a column `ParentId` linking to itself (So a category can have sub-categories)

EF automatically generates a property `Category1`, which is the parent category.

For the sake of clarity, I created another property

```
public partial class Category
{
  public Category Parent
  {
    get { return Category1; }
  }
}
```

The problem is, this works

```
var categs = ctx.Categories.Where(x => x.Category1 == null);
```

but this doesn't work

```
var categs = ctx.Categories.Where(x => x.Parent == null);
```

> The specified type member 'Parent' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Is there any way to create a translatable property (LINQ to SQL) without doing .ToList()?

EDIT: I want to avoid touching Model.edmx because the database often changes during development and the .edmx often needs to be recreated

Comment: you need to create a navigation property from category to parent like foreign key

Comment: Hi Cold Told, sorry I'm not sure what you mean. There is already a foreign key (Otherwise EF will not create Category1)

Comment: Have you actually looked at `Category1` in Model.Designer.cs and/or Reflector to see what attributes or other paraphernalia is added to its definition?

Comment: Yeah but I don't understand it, I tried copying them but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask if it's possible to create a property with any C# code in the getters/setters and later have it understood by standard LINQ to Entities - then no, it can't be done. C# is much more expressive then SQL and it's unreasonable to expect Entity Framework to act as a general C# to SQL translator.

You can work around this is many cases though, see [Using a partial class property inside LINQ statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879529/using-a-partial-class-property-inside-linq-statement/6927445) for an example.

**Update**

It'd help if you told us what exactly you want to achieve, but here's an example:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public static Expression<Func<Category, bool>> ParentIsNullExpression
    {
        get 
        {
            return c => c.Category1 == null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then

```
var categs = ctx.Categories.Where(Category.ParentIsNullExpression);
```

All sorts of manipulations on Expressions are possible, some of them are supported by EF and as such translate to SQL.

Comment: It can't be done in C#? But Model.Designer.cs itself (the CS file for EDMX) is C#, isn't it?? Are you referring to Properties returning Expressions from that link? I'll look at it.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the Expression Properties. It's not the property code that makes it work in Model.Designer.cs, it's the expression you use to access the property, e.g. ``c => c.Category``. EF knows that you want the ``Category`` property and translates that to ``Category`` column/table.

Comment: Sorry I've never used Expression Properties. Are you saying it's possible that an Expression Property gets translated to SQL? Can you replace the Parent property in my question with an Expression Property so LINQ can translate it? Thanks Jacek

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you Jacek for the complete answer! It's <Cateogry,bool> btw

Answer (score 0):

in your Entity Data Model Designer (.edmx file), you can rename the `Category1` to `Parent`

Comment: That was just a very-simplified example. I was asking how to write a property, not renaming an existing one. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 options:

1. Use code first
2. Add it to the EDMX designer
3. Add your property to the CSDL section of the EDMX, add a column to the SSDL section of the EDMX, then map them to each other in the mapping section of the EDMX.
4. Bring the query into memory using .ToList() then use internal LINQ instead of LINQ to Entities.